# Coldfusion form not updating database

Tags: forms, coldfusion

I have a form that updates on the same page is it on...this form worked last week and I have not touched the code AT ALL. What could have changed? :\

"It is not working.." as in...once the information is submitted, the information in the database is not updated. :\

**NOTE: I KNOW I need to replace things with cfparam...don't worry about that part.**

Another Note: this page is included in a tabbed area (jquery UI tabs)

I have tried to debug this with firebug...but I get no errors... :\

Here is the code:

```
<!-- Submit form handles -->
<cfif isdefined("form.buttonGen")>

  <cfparam name="form.TeachingLevel" default="None">
  <cfif #form.FundSource# IS 'Other'>
    <cfset form.FundSource = #form.FundSourceOther#>
  </cfif>

  <cfquery name="savePeople" datasource="#sacsds#" username="#sacsuser#" password="#sacsuser#">
  UPDATE faculty.dbo.SACS_Person
  SET Status = '#form.Status#',
  FundSource = '#form.FundSource#',
  TeachingLevel = '#form.TeachingLevel#',
  TeachingFields = '#form.TeachingFields#',
  MeetsReq = '#form.MeetsReq#', 
  GraduateHours = '#form.GraduateHours#',
  MeetsQual = '#form.MeetsQual#',
  Justification = '#form.Justification#'
  WHERE IDNum = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#session.fperson#"> AND
  DeptCode = '#session.DeptCode#'
  </cfquery>


<cfif ISDEFINED("form.VitaFile") AND form.VitaFile IS NOT ''>


    <cffile action="upload" filefield="form.VitaFile" destination="#VitaLoc#" nameconflict="makeunique">
    <cfset form.VitaURL = "#VitaPath#/#cffile.serverfile#">
        <cfquery name="saveVita" datasource="#sacsds#" username="#sacsuser#" password="#sacsuser#">
        UPDATE faculty.dbo.SACS_Person
         SET vitaURL =   '#form.vitaURL#'
         WHERE idnum LIKE '#form.idnum#'
        AND  deptCode LIKE '#form.deptCode#'
        </cfquery>

</cfif>



</cfif>
<div id = "dialog2">
<b>Saved.</b> 
</div>





<!-- The form -->
<cfif session.security GT 1>
<h3><cfoutput>#getP.FullName#</cfoutput></h3>
<cfform  name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" id = "docForm" >
<table class = "general">
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Status</strong></td>
    <td><cfinput type="radio" name="Status" value="Regular Faculty" checked="checked" />
      Regular Faculty
      <cfif results.Status IS "Visiting Faculty"><cfinput type="radio" name="Status" value="Visiting Faculty"  CHECKED />
      <cfelse>
      <cfinput type="radio" name="Status" value="Visiting Faculty" />
      </cfif>
        Visiting Faculty<br />
      <cfif results.Status IS "Adjunct">
        <cfinput type="radio" name="Status" value="Adjunct" CHECKED />
        <cfelse>
        <cfinput type="radio" name="Status" value="Adjunct" /></cfif>
        Adjunct
      <cfif results.Status IS "Graduate or Teaching Assistant">
        <cfinput type="radio" name="Status" value="Graduate or Teaching Assistant" CHECKED />
      <cfelse>
        <cfinput type="radio" name="Status" value="Graduate or Teaching Assistant" />
      </cfif>
    Grad or Teaching Asst </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Funding Source</strong></td>
    <td>
    <cfinput type="radio" name="FundSource" value="EG" checked="checked" />
      E&amp;G
      <cfif results.FundSource IS "Grant Contract">
      <cfinput type="radio" name="FundSource" value="Grant Contract" CHECKED />
      <cfelse>
      <cfinput type="radio" name="FundSource" value="Grant Contract" />
      </cfif>
      Grant Contract
      <cfif results.FundSource IS "Auxiliary">
      <cfinput type="radio" name="FundSource" value="Auxiliary" CHECKED />
      <cfelse>
      <cfinput type="radio" name="FundSource" value="Auxiliary" />
      </cfif>
      Auxiliary<br />
      <cfif results.FundSource IS NOT "Grant Contract" AND results.FundSource IS NOT "Auxiliary" AND results.FundSource IS NOT "EG">
      <cfinput type="radio" name="FundSource" value="Other" CHECKED />
      <cfelse>
      <cfinput type="radio" name="FundSource" value="Other" />
      </cfif>
      Other:
     <cfif results.FundSource IS NOT "Grant Contract" AND results.FundSource IS NOT "Auxiliary" AND results.FundSource IS NOT "EG">
     <cfoutput>
    <cfinput type="text" name="FundSourceOther" size="35" value="#results.FundSource#" />
    </cfoutput>
    <cfelse>
    <cfinput type="text" name="FundSourceOther" size="35" value="" />
    </cfif>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Teaching Levels</strong></td>
    <td>
    <cfif FindNoCase('Lower Division', #results.TeachingLevel#) IS NOT 0>
    <cfinput type="checkbox" name="TeachingLevel" value="Lower Division" CHECKED />
    <cfelse>
    <cfinput type="checkbox" name="TeachingLevel" value="Lower Division" />
    </cfif>
      Lower Division
    <cfif FindNoCase('Masters', #results.TeachingLevel#) IS NOT 0>
    <cfinput type="checkbox" name="TeachingLevel" value="Masters" CHECKED />
    <cfelse>
    <cfinput type="checkbox" name="TeachingLevel" value="Masters" />
    </cfif>
    Master's
    <cfif FindNoCase('Doctorate', #results.TeachingLevel#) IS NOT 0>
    <cfinput type="checkbox" name="TeachingLevel" value="Doctorate" CHECKED />
    <cfelse>
    <cfinput type="checkbox" name="TeachingLevel" value="Doctorate" />
    </cfif>
    Doctorate<br />
    <cfif FindNoCase('Upper Division', #results.TeachingLevel#) IS NOT 0>
    <cfinput type="checkbox" name="TeachingLevel" value="Upper Division" CHECKED />
    <cfelse>
    <cfinput type="checkbox" name="TeachingLevel" value="Upper Division" />
    </cfif>
    Upper Division
    <cfif FindNoCase('Specialist', #results.TeachingLevel#) IS NOT 0>
    <cfinput type="checkbox" name="TeachingLevel" value="Specialist" CHECKED />
    <cfelse>
    <cfinput type="checkbox" name="TeachingLevel" value="Specialist" />
    </cfif>
    Specialist
    <cfif FindNoCase('None', #results.TeachingLevel#) IS NOT 0>
    <cfinput type="checkbox" name="TeachingLevel" value="None" CHECKED />
    <cfelse>
    <cfinput type="checkbox" name="TeachingLevel" value="None"  />
    </cfif>
    None </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Teaching Fields</strong></td>
    <td><cfinput type="text" name="TeachingFields" size="35" value="#results.TeachingFields#"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><strong>Meets faculty requirements based upon advanced academic work in the teaching fields.</strong><br />
      &nbsp;
      <cfinput type="radio" name="MeetsReq" value="Yes" checked="checked" />
      Yes
      <cfif results.MeetsReq IS "No">
      <cfinput type="radio" name="MeetsReq" value="No" CHECKED />
      <cfelse>
      <cfinput type="radio" name="MeetsReq" value="No"  />
      </cfif>

    No </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><strong>Graduate semester hours in teaching field</strong>
      <br />
      <cfinput type="radio" name="GraduateHours" value="0-17" checked="checked" />
      0-17
      <cfif results.GraduateHours IS "18-29">
      <cfinput type="radio" name="GraduateHours" value="18-29" CHECKED />
      <cfelse>
      <cfinput type="radio" name="GraduateHours" value="18-29" />
      </cfif>
      18-29
      <cfif results.GraduateHours IS "30+">
      <cfinput type="radio" name="GraduateHours" value="30+" CHECKED />
      <cfelse>
      <cfinput type="radio" name="GraduateHours" value="30+" />
      </cfif>
      30 and above </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><strong>Meets qualifications based upon &quot;demonstrated competencies and achievements that contribute to effective teaching and student learning outcomes&quot; in lieu of advanced academic preparation.</strong><br />
      <cfinput type="radio" name="MeetsQual" value="Yes" checked="checked" />
      Yes
      <cfif results.MeetsQual IS "No">
      <cfinput type="radio" name="MeetsQual" value="No" CHECKED />
      <cfelse>
      <cfinput type="radio" name="MeetsQual" value="No" />
      </cfif>
        No </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><strong>If &quot;yes&quot;, describe the manner in which the competence and achievement were demonstrated. If &quot;no,&quot; describe the circumstances justifying the hiring.</strong>

      <br />
      <br />
      <cftextarea name="Justification" cols="70" rows="5"><cfoutput>#results.Justification#</cfoutput></cftextarea>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
      <cfinput type="submit" name="buttonGen" id="buttonGen"  value="Save Changes"  />
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<cfoutput>
<cfinput type="hidden" name="VitaURL" value="#results.VitaURL#">
<cfinput type="hidden" name="CollegeCode" value="#session.CollegeCode#">
<cfinput type="hidden" name="DeptCode" value="#session.DeptCode#">
<cfinput type="hidden" name="IDNum" value="#session.fperson#">
</cfoutput>
</cfform>
<cfelse>
</cfif>
```

Comment: It seems unlikely _nothing_ has changed. But try some basic troubleshooting. Use something like Live HTTP Headers to see if a request is actually submitted. If yes, add some logging to the page so you can see _what_ was submitted. Is the CFIF clause (ie query) even executing? It yes, what sql is executing? It is always possible the WHERE clause is not finding any matching records.

Comment: Oh... Miserly men's tear flows on my cheek when I see such code style.

Comment: I have seen worse. In fact I am working on just such a legacy application now.. I would cry. But alas there is no time.

Comment: sorry...if my code is horrible ... I kind of have time limits...and I just have to do everything kind of fast :\ ...this is what you get when you are only being paid 11 dollars an hours 20 hrs a week...I'll doing some logging..

Comment: @Bri - _Nobody_ writes perfect code at first (..or ever). When I look back at code I wrote just a few years ago, I shudder. But we all learn and improve as we go along ;)

Comment: @Sergii, your English is grammatically incorrect but I'm not going to explain why or how you can improve it ;-) What I mean to demonstrate is that negative feedback without constructive criticism is unhelpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the jquery dialog that tells the user the content was saved...was preventing the query from running. Strange...oh well no pretty dialog. :\ Doesn't work with the way I have things going. I'd have to do my form stuff through ajax...I would just do that, but I don't have time. Thanks everyone...

PS: I'll work on my coding style. :)

Comment: Or you could find out why it's blocking the query from running and fix it ;)